# Double integral help?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I show that for $S = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ that $\int \int_S f(x,y) dx dy \neq \int \int_S f(x,y) dy dx$ and why does this not contradict Fubini's theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fubini's theorem requires that $\int_S |f(x,y)|$ exist which fails here. This wikipedia article actually adresses this example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions

Answer (score 0):

[Fubini's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FubiniTheorem.html) requires that the function $f$ be continuous on the rectangle on which you want to integrate.  The function you have listed is not continous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Ok, but how do I show the inequality if I can't compute it.

Comment: user45878's comment below points to [this example on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions) which shows what the integral equals in both orders.